# How to make viewpager to not load pages again if they are already loaded

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter

I have Viewpager with 7 tabs, like in play store if we tap on tab on main screen it loads and if we tap that tab again it does not, I want if i tap on tab 1 it should load then i lets tap on tab 7 and then i tap tab 1 again it should not load, and only load if some conditions met, how can i do this? right now its just simple view pager with adapter like:

```
  public class PagerNewProductAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter { 
      RealmList<SubCategory> categoryData;
      String categoryName;
      String categoryId;
      Env env;

      public PagerNewProductAdapter(Fragment fragment, RealmList<SubCategory> category, String categoryName, String categoryId, Env env) {
        super(fragment.getChildFragmentManager());
        categoryData = category;
        this.categoryId = categoryId;
        this.env = env;
        this.categoryName = categoryName;
      }

      @Override
      public int getCount() {
        return categoryData.size() + 2;
      }

      @Override
      public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment;
        if (position == 0) {
          fragment= ProductFragment.newInstance("2", categoryId, categoryName);
        } else if (position == 1) {
          fragment= ProductFragment.newInstance("3", categoryId, categoryName);
        } else {
          fragment= ProductFragment.newInstance("1", categoryData.get(position - 2).getCategoryId(), categoryName);
        }
        return fragment;
      }

      @Override
      public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        if (position == 0) {
          // return env.appSubcategoryViewAll;
          return env.appSubcategoryViewAll;
        } else if (position == 1) {
          return env.appDashboardCBrands;
        } else {
          return categoryData.get(position - 2).getName();
        }
     }
  }
```

Thanks

Comment: You can cache the Fragment in an Array.

Comment: How, can you explain

Answer (score 2):

Simply add setOffscreenPageLimit like this:

```
    viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
```

3 = Number of fragments inside viewpager.

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case you can use `SparseArray`

```
public class PagerNewProductAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
  private final SparseArray<Fragment> registeredFragments = new SparseArray<>();
  RealmList<SubCategory> categoryData;
  String categoryName;
  String categoryId;
  Env env;

  public PagerNewProductAdapter(Fragment fragment, RealmList<SubCategory> category, String categoryName, String categoryId, Env env) {
    super(fragment.getChildFragmentManager());
    categoryData = category;
    this.categoryId = categoryId;
    this.env = env;
    this.categoryName = categoryName;
  }

  @NonNull
  @Override
  public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    if (registeredFragments.get(position) == null) {
      Object fragment = super.instantiateItem(container, position);
      registeredFragments.put(position, (BaseFragment) fragment);
      return fragment;
    } else {
      return registeredFragments.get(position);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
    registeredFragments.remove(position);
  }

  @Override
  public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    Fragment fragment;
    if (position == 0) {
        fragment= ProductFragment.newInstance("2", categoryId, categoryName);
    } else if (position == 1) {
        fragment= ProductFragment.newInstance("3", categoryId, categoryName);
    } else {
        fragment= ProductFragment.newInstance("1", categoryData.get(position - 2).getCategoryId(), categoryName);
    }
    return fragment;
  }

  @Override
  public int getCount() {
    return categoryData.size() + 2;
  }



  @Override
  public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    if (position == 0) {
       // return env.appSubcategoryViewAll;
        return env.appSubcategoryViewAll;
    } else if (position == 1) {
        return env.appDashboardCBrands;
    } else {
        return categoryData.get(position - 2).getName();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: getItem will remain same? no change in implementation after intantiateItem? also what is the role of destroyItem

Comment: instantiateItem() calls the getItem method, which creates a new fragment. In the instantiation method, we return the previously created fragment in order to avoid creating another one. This is re-use. A method destroitem is needed to free fragments. In source code you can see destroyItem() save fragment state and remove fragment from transaction

Comment: Its not caching fragment, if I tapping on very first tab and then go to last tab and then again tapping very first tap, its loading again

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use Fragmentation. it is working as per your requirements. If you have any query please let me know.

Step 1:
Implement Fragmentation https://github.com/YoKeyword/Fragmentation

Step 2:
extents your activity from SupportActivity instead of AppCompatActivity
extents your fragment from SupportFragment instead of Fragment

Step 3:
Remove onresume and onpause method from your fragment

Step 4:
call onPause(); in onViewCreated method

```
@Override
    public void onSupportVisible() {
        super.onSupportVisible();
       onResume();
        if(!isLoaded){
            isLoaded = true;
//Load your data here 
}
}
@Override
    public void onSupportInvisible() {
        super.onSupportInvisible();
       onPause();
    }
```

Step 5: 
set setlimit
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(numberi);

Happy Coding.

Answer (score -1):

You can store the previously created Fragment in an Array. This ensures that we will use the previously created instance if it exists in our Array.

```
public class PagerNewProductAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter { 
      Fragment[] cache;
      RealmList<SubCategory> categoryData;
      ...

      public PagerNewProductAdapter(Fragment fragment, RealmList<SubCategory> category, String categoryName, String categoryId, Env env) {
        ...
        this.categoryName = categoryName;
        this.cache = new Fragment[getCount()];
      }

      @Override
      public int getCount() {
        return categoryData.size() + 2;
      }

      @Override
      public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        Fragment cachedFragment = cache[position]
        if(cachedFragment == null){
            if (position == 0) {
                cache[position] = ProductFragment.newInstance("2", categoryId, categoryName);
                cachedFragment = cache[position];
            } else if (position == 1) {
                cache[position] = ProductFragment.newInstance("3", categoryId, categoryName);
                cachedFragment = cache[position];
            } else {
                cache[position]= ProductFragment.newInstance("1", categoryData.get(position - 2).getCategoryId(), categoryName);
                cachedFragment = cache[position];
            }
        }
        return cachedFragment;
      }
      ...
  }
```